# Android Debug Tracing problem

Tags: android, debugging, trace, runtimeexception

I am testing my code in device and it is running fine. But as soon as I am adding `Debug.startMethodTracing("PlaceLocator");` and `Debug.stopMethodTracing();` , it is giving problem. As per log, problem is-

```
03-25 17:39:43.124: INFO/dalvikvm(5971): TRACE STARTED: '/sdcard/LineGraph.trace' 8192KB
03-25 17:39:43.124: ERROR/dalvikvm(5971): Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/LineGraph.trace': Permission denied
03-25 17:39:43.124: DEBUG/dalvikvm(5971): +++ active profiler count now 0
03-25 17:39:43.124: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(5971): Shutting down VM
03-25 17:39:43.124: WARN/dalvikvm(5971): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b170)
03-25 17:39:43.124: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5971): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-25 17:39:43.131: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5971): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.placeLocator/com.android.placeLocator.PlaceLocator}: java.lang.RuntimeException: file open failed
```

Here I like to mention that I have added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in the manifest so that system can write file in sd card. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure /sdcard exists and is writable?  Can you "adb shell echo blah > /sdcard/test" successfully?  Is the uses-permission in the correct part of the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying this on emulator ? If so you may want to configure your emulator with external storage.

Or try loging into shell 'adb shell' and try to create a file in /sdcard/LineGraph.trace.

You can

echo "something" > /sdcard/LineGraph.trace

and see if the file is created.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#knownissues, there are known issues with profiling and threads.  I found that if I use any threads, my application crashes.